# SUM(tablename/60) How to implement this?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sum

This is one line from my stored procedure. My table field hoursworked is storing minutes. How to store it by dividing it to 60.

```
(select 
    SUM(ISNULL(hoursworked,0)) 
 from 
    UserTime 
 where 
    userid = @employeeid 
    and convert(varchar(100),checkin,106) = convert(varchar(100),@Startdate,106) 
    and loginstatus= 'Out') 


hoursworked as int
```

how can I implement this

```
SUM(ISNULL(hoursworked/60,0))
```

Comment: what happened when you tired that ??

Comment: I tried your version and it seems to work. What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you probably got is `0`.  You should do the `sum()` first:

```
coalesce(sum(hoursworked)/60, 0)
```

The problem is that SQL Server does integer division, so any value less than 60 (and greater than or equal to 0) will result in `0`. You might really want:

```
coalesce(sum(hoursworked)/60.0, 0)
```